# How to make plain text which appears after scanning a QR clickable and redirects the user to the browser?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have written a piece of code for scanning QR code. But after scanning it is showing the data in plain text even if it is a link or URL to some website. I want it to redirects the user to the particular website after scanning directly in the browser.

```
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
       // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
       // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); 
// Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        MainActivity.tvresult.setText(rawResult.getText());
        onBackPressed();

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
```

Comment: And where is the code for doing so? Probably, you want to check whatever `getText` returns, and react to that?

Comment: Have you tried any answer Tabish? you have to accept and mark it as a correct if any was suseful....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this attribute to your `TextView`

```
<Textview 
          android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Other option is to create an `Intent` for that when user click on your `TextView`

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(rawResult.getText());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent)
```

Better way also can be create a `Linkify`

```
Linkify.addLinks(tvresult, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

You can choose what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Make a TextView which you are showing text in it clickable in .xml file:

```
<Textview 
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"/>
```